# Magento 1.4 - Get the quantity of most selling products

Tags: magento

What is the php/magento code I can use to get the best selling products and display that name of the product.

For example, say I've sold 10 Foos, 20 Bars and 50 Bazes.  I want to know how to query the Magento system and have it say "Bazes" are the high selling products (with 50).

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reports are a little weird, as they're implemented using collections that don't have a parent model.  Try the following

```
$c = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_bestsellers_collection');         
foreach($c as $item)
{
    var_dump($item->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento admin already has this.

- Go to the menu Reports > Products > Bestsellers.
- Make the "From" date sometime in the past, like January 1st.
- Make the "To" date today or sometime in the future.
- Change "Show by" to "Year" and click Refresh.